# How to formally insert URL space (%20) using Python?

Tags: python, url, urllib2, urllib, url-encoding

When a mutli-word search term is entered in ebay, the resultant URL looks something like (for example "demarini cf5 cf12"):

```
http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_sacat=0&amp;_nkw=demarini%20cf5%20cfc12
```

I wish to construct this URL in Python so it can be accessed directly. So it's case of concatenating the base URL:

```
http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_sacat=0&amp;_nkw=
```

... with the search term. Right now. I am adding the `%20` for the spaces explicately thus:

```
baseUrl = 'http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&amp;_sacat=0&amp;_nkw='
searchTerm = 'demarini cf5 cf12'
searchTerm = ('%20').join(searchTerm.split(' '))
finalUrl = baseUrl + searchTerm
```

What is a more formal way of doing this in Python? I believe the name for this sort of task is URL encoding?

Comment: You probably want `urllib.quote()`.

Comment: The *proper* way of encoding a space in the *query string* of a URL is the `+` sign. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) and the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). As such `urllib.quote_plus()` should be used instead when encoding just one key or value, or use `urllib.urlencode()` when you have a dictionary or sequence of key-value pairs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the comprehensive answer as always, Martijn.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `urllib` library

```
import urllib
finalurl = baseUrl + urllib.parse.quote(searchterm)
```

you can use quote_plus() to add + insted of %20
to undo this use

```
urllib.parse.unquote(str)
```

In Python 2, use `urllib.quote()` and `urllib.unquote()` respectively